# setText to TextView when using the inflater

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

In my android app i have been using the RelativeLayout and inflater. so i need to set the text in textView, which i have used with Inflater, but i cannot set the text by code.

**XML file activity_title**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**2 xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
             >
</RelativeLayout>
```

so this is the code, which using the inflater

```
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_container);
    ((ViewGroup) relativeLayout).removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < titleCalendar.length; i++) {
        getApplicationContext();
        vi= (LayoutInflater)
  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_title, null);  
        textViewC = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        textViewC.setText("sdfsfasfasfasfasf");
        textViewC.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, addcnvrtTime);


        textViewC.setLayoutParams(params);
        ((ViewGroup) relativeLayout).addView(v, 0, params);

    }
```

I cannot see the text, which i set on that textview

Comment: background-color white aswell? :)

Comment: what is addcnvrtTime ?

Comment: that just one value that giving some integer number, for show the next text position, have any issue with that?

Comment: I guess I don't see why your even inflating the textview from xml anyways. Why not just create one programatically and add it to the container. Its essentially the same thing your doing but doesn't involve an expensive xml inflation

Comment: I have tried that way, but that had one problem, for textview loading in the relativelayout

Answer (score 2):

This is to get Inflater elements:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_INFLATER, null);
TextView text = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW);
text.setText("BlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
```

Why not put TextView direct inside the Layout and simply do

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW);
text.setText("BlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
```

?

Comment: I have already did that, but that time i cannot update the relativelayout with previous elements textview

Comment: Can you explain a little more your problem? Im not understanding what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

try remove params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, addcnvrtTime)?